# What are the criteria to take in mind before submitting extension in JED?

Tags: extensions, jed

I have used **JED checker** to analyze if my extension is valid to submit in JED.
But also i want to know major or minor things to consider before **submitting extension** in JED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla! Docs has an article about [Publishing to JED](https://docs.joomla.org/Publishing_to_JED), with a quite complete list that includes things to consider in addition to the coding part.

Among other things it's important to consider:

1. Licensing (must be GPL to be accepted)
2. Packing ([recommendations here](https://docs.joomla.org/Extensions_packing))
3. Distribution - where the files can be downloaded

A couple of things won't directly affect your submission, but should also be taken into account:

1. Price (free or commercial)
2. Support

Finally, take a look at the [JED Entries Submission Checklist](https://docs.joomla.org/JED_Entries_Submission_Checklist), it's a complete checklist with mostly anything you need to check before submitting an extension.

Answer (score 3):

Providing you have used the JED checker, there isn't really anything else you need to take into consideration for the submission, however there are some things that you may want to take into consideration on the development side.

**Security** and **up to date coding standards** are 2 major things. Please do ensure that for things like:

- Database queries
- Importing JS/CSS files
- Getting `POST/GET` variables

that you have read the documentation and used the methods provided.

There's nothing worse that seeing extensions that are

- using native SQL or old coding standards for DB queries
- Importing jQuery using a `<script>` tag
- Use `JRequest` for Joomla 3.x

So my advice would simply be to look through the code for your extension, and the Joomla documentation to ensure it's all hunky doory.